# How can I use linq to initialize an array of repeated elements?

Tags: c#, linq

At present, I'm using something like this to build a list of 10 objects:

```
myList = (from _ in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select new MyObject {...}).toList()
```

This is based off my python background, where I'd write:

```
myList = [MyObject(...) for _ in range(10)]
```

Note that I want my list to contain 10 instances of my object, not the same instance 10 times.

Is this still a sensible way to do things in C#? Is there a cost to doing it this way over a simple for loop?

Comment: Are you using the Range value somewhere in MyObject, or just need any arbitrary objects?

Comment: @Tilak: Arbitrary objects (hence the underscore)

Comment: IMO simple for loop is be negligibly better(readability/performance) rather than LINQ query.

Comment: >> Is there a cost to doing it this way over a simple for loop? : Yes, Loop is executed 3 times, that the only cost.

Comment: @tilak: Surely the loop is executed only once, when `.toList` is invoked

Answer (score 12):

Fluent API looks a little more readable in this case, but its not very easy to see the intent of your code:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => new MyObject()).ToList();
```

Simple if loop is fast and easy to understand, but it also hides intent - creating list of 10 items

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     list.Add(new MyObject());
```

The best thing for readability is a builder, which will describe your intent

```
public class Builder<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public static IList<T> CreateListOfSize(int size)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            list.Add(new T());
        return list;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = Builder<MyObject>.CreateListOfSize(10);
```

This solution is as fast, as simple loop, and intent is very clear. Also in this case we have minimum amount of code to write.

Comment: Pretty sure `Enumerable.Range(0, 10)` gives 11 values

Comment: @Eric pretty sure second parameter is `count`

Comment: All good if you only need to use the default constructor of `T`, otherwise passing in a construction delegate might be preferable.

Comment: @spender agree, also `(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args)` is an option to create instance and pass parameters to constructor

Comment: I don't think the intent is non-ambiguously clear in this case.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thank you for your answer!
Why in the builder did you use IList instead List as a return type?

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x => new MyObject()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think `Enumerable.Repeat` is missing an overload. A handy addition would be something like this:

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(int amt, Func<T> producer)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < amt; ++i)
        {
            yield return producer();
        }
    }
}
```

so you could

```
EnumerableEx.Repeat(10, () => new object()) //.ToList()
```

Comment: An overload wouldn't cut it - you wouldn't be able to create an iterable of a function repeated 10 times.

Comment: Scratch that - you can distinguish the two cases by the return type